# Mssql is not compiled into PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, pear, mdb2

I have pear and mssql installed on my ubuntu server 16.04, but while connecting it shows an error message

> [Error message: extension mssql is not compiled into PHP]

Can anybody, please, help me avoid that error?

Comment: Try [this](https://coderwall.com/p/21uxeq/connecting-to-a-mssql-server-database-with-php-on-ubuntu-debian) ([archived](http://archive.is/L5nJ2)/[archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318050118/https://coderwall.com/p/21uxeq/connecting-to-a-mssql-server-database-with-php-on-ubuntu-debian))

Comment: It shows an warring message as                                                      WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libssl1.0.2 libgd3 php5-mysql php5-readline php5-cli php5-mcrypt php5-gd      so it stops their installation
  libapache2-mod-php5 php5-common php5-sybase

Comment: ..so then you [Google _that_ question](https://www.google.com/search?q="The+following+packages+cannot+be+authenticated") and [fix that too](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2334871&s=58b5a392f83d264d3fd6248604cc2bd7&p=13534860#post13534860)?